# How to create a staggered 2 col gird view with 2nd col slightly below first column

Tags: html, css

I want to build a layout with two col-gird with the same height and width. But, 2nd column should be aligned slightly below the first column using CSS.

Adding an image for reference below:

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add your code or what you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

Happy to help! All the finished code is below.

Answer: That's really simple. You can use the `::last-child` selector.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="column"> First Child </div>
        <div class="column"> Last Child </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
        <div class="column"> First Child </div>
        <div class="column"> Last Child </div>
</div>
```

This is how you use it. It's pretty simple.

```
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(167, 167, 167);
    color: white;
    margin: 15px;
}

.column:last-child {
    top: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Note: the `:last-child` selector is used on the child not the parent. so `:last-child` on an element means the last element of it's parent.

Ideally you would want to put `position: relative;` in `.column {..` but for this example, I will put it in `column:last-child` because you need `position:...` to be able to use `top:___` and other position *things*.

A quick explanation: you're setting `row`'s display to `display: flex;` which align things INSIDE IT (not itself) horizontally. Each row contains 2 columns so two rows means 4 columns.

Quick sum-up: 1 row has 2 columns, the last column will have `top:15px` to move it down slightly.

Here is all the code!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        .row {
            display: flex;
        }

        .column {
            width: 100px;
            position: relative;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: rgb(167, 167, 167);
            color: white;
            margin: 15px;
        }

        .column:last-child {
            top: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>YEAHHHHHHHH</h2>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```